# Get working directory of another Java process

Tags: java, windows, process, java-8, working-directory

I can get working directory of current Java program using this code:
`Path path = Paths.get(*ClassName*.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());`

Also I can get CommandLine parameters (but there is no directory in the output) of running Java processes using this command `wmic process get CommandLine where name='java.exe' /value`

It is possible to get working directory of another Java process (better programmatically)? Probably it can be solved with some jdk/bin utilities?

Comment: *ClassName*.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI() will fail in some circumstances.  If you want the current directory, why not just use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`?

Comment: `getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` will give you the *code location* (as the name suggests), which is *not* necessarily identical to the working directory. That should be obvious when considering that different classes have different code sources. Further, converting that location to a `Path` via `Paths.get` will only work, if it is a `file:` URI, but fail, e.g. for classes contained in a jar file. If you want a `Path` representing the working directory, `Paths.get("")` is sufficient, if you want to know its current absolute path, well use `Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath()`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information via the [Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html). To use it, you have to add the `tools.jar` of your jdk to your class path. Then, the following code will print the current working directories of all recognized JVM processes:

```
for(VirtualMachineDescriptor d: VirtualMachine.list()) {
    System.out.println(d.id()+"\t"+d.displayName());
    try {
        VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(d);
        try(Closeable c = vm::detach) {
            System.out.println("\tcurrent dir: "+vm.getSystemProperties().get("user.dir"));
        }
    }
    catch(AttachNotSupportedException|IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("\t"+ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed responses. Do I correct understand that I need to copy `tools.jar` from `...jdk/lib` folder to my application's `lib` folder and then include it in the class path? I mean that I can not include it from JDK, because it will not work in other environments, right?

Comment: The `tools.jar`, you refer to when compiling, doesn’t have to be the same as you refer to when launching you application. So you can refer to the `tools.jar` of your current JDK when compiling and refer to the the runtime’s `tools.jar` when running the application, assuming that it does run on a jdk rather than a naked jre (I’m looking forward to Java 9 which is supposed to get rid of this distinction). I recommend users to install JDKs anyway, even if they are not developing, as it doesn’t try to install crapware (and it’s not so long ago, when the server JVM was only available in the JDK)

Comment: Please, can you help me one more time? I use your code and everything is works in IDE (Eclipse), but after compilation I getting this error `java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider: Provider sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated`. I launch the program with this command `java -Xmx512m -cp program.jar;lib\* xx.Program`. All needed files exist in the lib folder. I tried both locations in class path, also tried add ...jdk/lib directory to the PATH variable. Maybe problem in java.exe instead of javaw.exe in Eclipse?

Comment: I get it. Having standard java `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` environment variable before actual JDK path.